# Circular magnetic field around current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics

We know that a current carrying wire produce a magnetic field around it.But my question is why those magnetic lines are circles.
How it can be like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can derive it directly from the Biot Savart law. Let's say we have an infinite wire with a uniform current running up the $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$-axis, because of the vertical translation symmetry we can take our observation point to lie on the x axis some perpendicular distance $\rho$ from the vertical , and so
$$\mathbf{B}=\frac{\mu I_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}\times d\mathbf{z}}{\rho^2+z^2}.$$
The cross product equals $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the source and the observation point. We then have
$$\mathbf{B}=\frac{\mu I_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\rho \ dz}{(\rho^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\hat{\phi}.$$
$$\mathbf{B}=\frac{\mu I_0}{4\pi}\frac{2}{\rho}=\frac{\mu I_0}{2\pi\rho}$$